# How to add a bar graph to my dashboard using just the counts from excel and displaying it like a graph

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I wanted to add bar graph to my dashboard using the live data. The below code just shows the value  in a box. I will be manually running my app and publishing it to server. when ever i run my code it will pick the updated record count from excel and will display. As of today i added the counts. For say today i have 5000 records. By end of this month i might have 10000 records.How can i show it like a graph (The bar has to move ) not sure how much will be the count for end of this year. So when i tried to use progress bar i cant predict the year end count and give it as value.Not sure how i can do this. Please help me on this

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny) # Shiny web app
library(DT) # for data tables
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
#tbl1 <- read_excel('BIRTH_2020.XLSX')
ui <- dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(disable = TRUE),
        dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
        dashboardBody(
                fluidPage(
                        valueBoxOutput("total_counts")
                )
        )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
        ({
        tbl1 <-  read_excel('Test1.XLSX')
        })
        
      data <-  reactive({
              sum(tbl1$TOTAL)
               
        })

        output$total_counts <- renderValueBox({
                valueBox(
                        data(),
                        "Total Counts- 2021 "
                )
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: you have to refresh the `read_excel` part. Manually using a button or automatically with code recognizing when the excel file has new data.

Comment: I can get the refreshed data when ever i run my app. But i wanted to display the data as bar graph

Comment: I see. Why not using renderPlot with ggplot or barplot?

Comment: Yes but how can I define when I don't have X and Y axis. I just have a count. So tried using  slider input . But slider input is not taking the dynamic value. Here is the code - ui <- fluidPage(
           sliderInput("data", "Total counts",0,100000, value = c(data()))

)
server <- function(input, output) {
        ({
                        tbl1 <-  read_excel('test1.xlsx')
          })

          data <-  reactive({
                      sum(tbl1$TOTAL)

            })
        }

Comment: So your data() is always one numeric value like `100`?

Comment: Yes.. The Value will always be retrieved from my excel

Comment: and this is not suitable? `ggplot(data.frame(y=100), aes(x="1", y = y)) + geom_col() + xlab("this is my value") + theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())`